# SSIS: Fixed Width Columns Aren't Displaying Correctly

Tags: ssis

I am trying to create a fixed width flat file import spec in SSIS.  When I set up all of the columns with the correct widths and preview them, the first row is correct but all of the other rows are off.

example:

> Row 1:  Text
>
> Row 2:  [space]Text
>
> Row 3:  [space][space]Text

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your actual delimiter in the flat file import source?

Comment: There is no delimiter.  For example, if the first 12 characters were ABCDEFGHIJKL, then it would be col 1 - ABCDE, col 2 - F, col 3 - GHIJ, col 4 - KL, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced something similar to this whenever I first sat up a fixed width column and did not properly adjust for the data between the end of text (or delimiter) to the next line.  The data in this area is usually spacing and the carriage return/line feed.  To adjust properly, I created one extra column that handled the data from the end of text (or delimiter) to the next line.  This fixed my spacing issue.

Comment: David - thanks for the answer, I hadn't even thought of that.  This does work but is there a reason that this happens?  Am I doing something wrong in building the import that it's not recognizing that carriage return?

Comment: It could be that it's a Lf instead of a CrLf, or a Cr instead of a Lf (etc) in the flat file for carriage return.

Comment: Jay's answer could be correct.  My experience is mainly with SSIS 2005.  I viewed this as a bug; however, since windows use a combination of CrLf to detect the end of the line, I guess it is correct to say that the CrLf is part of the row.  Thus we truly have two columns.  Nonetheless its quite aggravating until you figure it out..

Is this modified in any other versions of SSIS?

Comment: Same thing happens with 2008, though the CR/LF characters show up as squares in the preview so it's more obvious.